# What's the relationship of h2o-bindings and h2o-genmodel

Tags: h2o

H2O have so many submodules, what's the relationship of them?

I created a flow by using h2o-bindings, but I can't get a MOJO model from the result.

I searched the answer and found that I have to add dependency of h2o-genmodel.
But I'm still cannot get the mojo model from the result created by h2o-bindings.

So what's the relationship of h2o-bindings and h2o-genmodel?
What should I do if I want to train my data, get the mojo model and use it to build a tree in java?

This is my code using h2o-bindings.

```
@Override
ModelMetricsListSchemaV3 train(H2oApi h2o) throws IOException {

    DRFParametersV3 drfParams = new DRFParametersV3();
    drfParams.trainingFrame = H2oApi.stringToFrameKey("train");
    drfParams.validationFrame = H2oApi.stringToFrameKey("test");
    drfParams.ntrees=3;

    ColSpecifierV3 responseColumn = new ColSpecifierV3();
    responseColumn.columnName = ATT_LABEL_GOLF;
    drfParams.responseColumn = responseColumn;

    DRFV3 drfBody = h2o.train_drf(drfParams);

    JobV3 job = h2o.waitForJobCompletion(drfBody.job.key);

    ModelKeyV3 modelKey = (ModelKeyV3)job.dest;
    ModelsV3 models = h2o.model(modelKey);
    DRFModelV3 model = (DRFModelV3)models.models[0];

    //I want to get mojo model but the output isn't right.
    ModelExportV3 modelExportV3 = h2o.exportMojo(modelKey);

    ModelMetricsListSchemaV3 predictParams = new ModelMetricsListSchemaV3();
    predictParams.model = modelKey;
    predictParams.frame = drfParams.trainingFrame;
    predictParams.predictionsFrame = H2oApi.stringToFrameKey("predictions");
    System.out.println(predictParams);

    return predictParams;
}
```

Comment: There is no direct relationship.  h2o-genmodel is meant to be usable standalone.  Downloading a mojo gives you a zip file artifact, and then you load that with the h2o-genmodel API.  I suggest you follow one of the examples to build a mojo in R or Python first since they are more used, better supported and better documented.  Once you can do that, you can try the bindings again if you still want to.

Comment: I can find the code of how to download mojo model in R or Python, but I didn't find the java example code. I used the h2o-genmodel to train data but there is no h2o.downloadMojo() method. There is a  method called "ModelExportV3 modelExportV3 = h2o.exportMojo(model.modelId);" but the result isn't a zip file.